# Dispose user created bindingContext knockout

Tags: javascript, templates, knockout.js, jsrender

In our scenario need to create ko template inside js-render template. Need to create grid like item where

```
<tr>
<td>...
</td>
....

<td>Ko template 
</td>


</tr>
```

Here we need to create childcontext which is used to render those ko template elements with data.

How we can dispose the child binding context created ?

The concept is to have grid like appearance and we bind datasource (records) to table. Inside table we have the ko template, since we need to bind this template with data externally i am creating new binding context for it with data iteration

```
 bindingContext = new ko.bindingContext();
        if (!ej.isNullOrUndefined(index)) {
            if (!bindingContext.items)
                bindingContext.items = [];
            bindingContext.items[index] = data;
        } else {
            index = 1;
            bindingContext.items = [data];
        }
```

and render it using renderTemplate method

```
for (var i = 0; i < el.length;i++) {
                ko.renderTemplate(template.replace("#", ""), tmpl[template]["bindingContext"]["items"][i], {}, el[i]);
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean by disposing a binding context? I think this is something knockout and regular garbage collection take care of for you. You might need to show a bit more code or explain what you're trying to do better...

Comment: @user3297291 i have provided more details, could you please check now.